# How to get the last object from a query?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have the following:

```
// In the service
me: Ember.computed('token', function() {
  return this.container.lookup('service:store').findRecord('user', 63);
}

// In the template - Works
{{this.currentSession.me.profile.firstName}}
```

Above works as expected. However, if I replace `findRecord` with `query` and throw it a `filter` param:

```
// In the service
me: Ember.computed('token', function() {
  return this.container.lookup('service:store').query('user', { filter: { token: this.get('token') } });
}

// In the template - Works
{{this.currentSession.me.lastObject.profile.firstName}}
```

The `lastObject` is required, since the result from `query` is a collection. I am wondering if it is possible to get this work without doing `lastObject`. i.e.

```
{{this.currentSession.me.profile.firstName}}
```

I tried to put the `lastObject` in the computed property, like:

```
return this.container.lookup('service:store').query('user', { filter: { token: this.get('token') } }).lastObject;
```

To no avail. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return this.container.lookup('service:store').query('user', { filter: { token: this.get('token') } }).then(function(users){
  return users.get('lastObject');
});
```

Comment: `{{log this.currentSession.me.id}}` in the template, returns `undefined`. However, `{{log this.currentSession.me}}` returns a promise: `Promise {_id: 103, _label: undefined, _state: undefined, _result: undefined, _subscribers: Array[0]…}`

Comment: @ChristianFazzini Hmm. Is query returning any users? If the query is returning a collection, this would be how you returned the last object. See: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/guvucunipa/2/edit?html,css,js,output Maybe check your request to see if all the request and response looks right?